# Azure App registration add authorized client applications through powershell Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

How to add authroized client applications (in portal : app registration -> Expose API -> add Authorized client applications) during app registration using powershell Azure CLI.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is ***no az command to directly add preauthorized clients to a app registration*** instead you will have to ***use Graph API (beta) to update the same from ***[`Graph Explorer`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)*** or ***[`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest)*** command.***

**Get OauthPermissionId with az command :**

```
az ad app show --id $appId --query "oauth2Permissions[].id"
```

***I tested the same from Graph Explorer :***

[image]

***Ran `Patch : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<appObjectId>`***

***With Request body as :***

```
{
    "api": {
        "preAuthorizedApplications": [
            {
                "appId": "authorizedappClientID",
                "permissionIds": [
                    "oauth2PermissionId"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

**Reference for az rest can be fount in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685667/how-to-add-preauthorizedapplications-using-cli-2-x) answered by Joy Wang .**