# Problem with setting preAuthorizedApplications in Azure app registration with Az Powershell 7.1.0

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, microsoft-graph-api

I have a problem with automating the setting of the preAuthorizedApplications for a Azure app registration from Az powershell 7.1.0. The code is making a transition to the MS Graph api's, but the syntax of the preAuthorizedApplications is not clear to me. Everything i found on the net, i tried. But nothing works and keeps erroring out.

I created a piece of test code and a test app registration:

Get-AzADApplication -ApplicationId 956afe7b-f58f-4de5-83ea-02035cc98b3f # Just to get the Types

$PreAuthPrem1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphPreAuthorizedApplication"
$PreAuthPrem1.AppId = "1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264"
$PreAuthPrem1.DelegatedPermissionId = "d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"

Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId 956afe7b-f58f-4de5-83ea-02035cc98b3f -api @{"preAuthorizedApplications" = $PreAuthPrem1} -debug

It keep giving me the same error, what is not very helpfull:

Line |
549 |      Az.MSGraph.internal\Update-AzADApplication @PSBoundParameters
|      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Property preAuthorizedApplications in payload has a value that does not match schema.

The request to MS graph is below (taken from the debug command)

DEBUG: ============================ HTTP REQUEST ============================

HTTP Method:
PATCH

Absolute Uri:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ccd14ce8-1afe-45b3-a461-777d3129399b

Headers:
x-ms-unique-id                : 6
x-ms-client-request-id        : cb41d352-4b67-4142-8795-9b77bf9b057a
CommandName                   : Az.MSGraph.internal\Update-AzADApplication
FullCommandName               : Update-AzADApplication_UpdateExpanded
ParameterSetName              : __AllParameterSets
User-Agent                    : AzurePowershell/v0.0.0,Az.MSGraph/5.2.0

Body:
{
"api": {
"preAuthorizedApplications": "{\r\n  "appId": "1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264",\r\n  "delegatedPermissionIds": [ "d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162" ]\r\n}"
}
}

I found documentation to with says it should be delegatedPermissionIds but also that is should be permissionIds. Both do not work for me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadapplication?view=azps-7.1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/preauthorizedapplication?view=graph-rest-1.0

Also it tried other ways of setting the body to not include the specials characters but everything just keeps giving the same error.

Also updated the az powershell (to 7.1.0) and powershell itself (7.2.1 core)

Also tried with azure ClI

$appObjectId='956afe7b-f58f-4de5-83ea-02035cc98b3f'

az rest -m PATCH -u https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$appObjectId --headers Content-Type=application/json -b '{"api":{"preAuthorizedApplications":[{"appId":"1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264","permissionIds":["d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"]}]}}'

Bad Request({"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.","innerError":{"date":"2022-01-31T06:23:44","request-id":"2ac51323-4f9b-4da8-8ec8-1187e4b73a59","client-request-id":"2ac51323-4f9b-4da8-8ec8-1187e4b73a59"}}})

Looks like the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked in my Devops pipeline. I gave the service principle the rights and enabled access on to the token.

```
$Body = @"
{
    "api": {
        "preAuthorizedApplications": [
            {
                "appId": "1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264",
                "permissionIds": [
                    "d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
"@

$Uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/ccd14ce8-1afe-45b3-a461-777d3129399b'
$method = 'PATCH'
$Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).Token

$Header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method $method -Headers $Header -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $Body
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same in our environment as an alternate solution we can try [***`Graph Explorer`***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) .

To do that we have to get our Oauth2Permissions id from manifest or by running the below code we can get :

```
az ad app show --id $appId --query "oauth2Permissions[].id"
```

[image]

Now we need to use graph explorer to achieve the above requirement by mention the following in our request body by using below method:

***`Patch : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<appObjectId>`***

**Request body** :

```
{
    "api": {
        "preAuthorizedApplications": [
            {
                "appId": "authorizedappClientID",
                "permissionIds": [
                    "oauth2PermissionId"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

***Provide the object id of the application in above given URI.***

- Allow the following consent > Modify permission
- And check your permission ID by navigate to manifest if that is correct or not.
  [image]
  ***OUTPUT:-***

[image]
[image]

For use `az rest` please refer this [***`SO THREAD`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685667/how-to-add-preauthorizedapplications-using-cli-2-x) .

Comment: Hi Ajay... i already saw this thread, and this does not seem to work for me.  I used the following command:

az rest --method patch --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/956afe7b-f58f-4de5-83ea-02035cc98b3f" --headers '{"Content-Type":"application/json"}' --body '{"api":{"preAuthorizedApplications":[{"appId":"5e3ce6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-75ee78787346","permissionIds":["d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"]}]}}'

Which resulted in error

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Also the graph explorer errors out with:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unexpected contents in request body.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-01-31T12:38:50",
            "request-id": "a6ccdf48-75f2-41ad-8e98-0e2fd9109b3b",
            "client-request-id": "a9ae6a02-b614-d9a8-014b-12a40f1bea63"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please make sure to consent all that show in modify permission

Comment: Yes i did... but still the same error..
these are the permission taken from my JWT token:

AppCatalog.Read.All AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All OnlineMeetings.Read OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite openid profile User.Read email Application.ReadWrite.All

Comment: It is beginning to feel like a bug. Maybe because of the move from the Azure AD api's to the MS Graph api's

Comment: No its working fine, Please make sure the permission ID you have provided as same as on manifest (oauth2 permissions sections)

Comment: Hi Ajay... that was the missing thing for the graph explorer. I will now try in azure cli to see if can make that work as well

Comment: I tried the az cli command: az rest --method patch --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/ccd14ce8-1afe-45b3-a461-777d3129399b" --headers '{"Content-Type":"application/json"}' --body '{"api":{"preAuthorizedApplications":[{"appId":"1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264","permissionIds":["d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"]}]}}'

But this give the error:

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The body is exactly the same as used in the graph explorer

Comment: Hi Ajay.. i got it working in powershell in my DevOps pipe line. So thanks for your help ! Couldnt do it without you

Comment: For the completeness, my powershell code:
$Body = @"
{
    "api": {
        "preAuthorizedApplications": [
            {
                "appId": "1fec8e78-bce4-4aaf-ab1b-5451cc387264",
                "permissionIds": [
                    "d3a943ac-ea3b-4271-b750-abcd91b01162"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
"@

Comment: $Uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/ccd14ce8-1afe-45b3-a461-777d3129399b'
$method = 'PATCH'
$Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph).Token

Write-Host $Token

$Header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method $method -Headers $Header -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $Body